# How to start OpenGL in software emulation mode?

Tags: opengl

Is there any way I can start OpenGL in software emulation mode, like DirectX where there is reference rendering option?

Comment: Initializing OpenGL is VERY platform-specific.  So tell us what OS you're using, and whether you're using any wrapper library, such as SDL.

Comment: What does that mode do? Render with CPU instead of GPU, or something else? Force CPU rendering at: http://superuser.com/questions/106056/force-software-based-opengl-rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are trying to just test your existing software there are a bunch of tricks... like:
http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=148011

if you are writing software and have the ability to specify the render... then in windows:

from: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/mswindows.htm

> To force software rendering from your application, choose a pixel
>   format that is not hardware accelerated. To do this, you can not use
>   ChoosePixelFormat(), which always selects a hardware accelerated pixel
>   format when one is available. Instead, use DescribePixelFormat() to
>   iterate through the list of available pixel formats. Any format with
>   the PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT attribute bit set will not be hardware
>   accelerated.

for linux or mac... I would have to look through real books... let me know if you are on linux/Mac