# Building Mesa for windows 7. Mesa 9.1

Tags: python, c, opengl, mesa

I went through all the steps on the compiling / installing page on Mesa's site, and read the FAQ.  The final command that you send to scons for compilation throws errors within python scripts.  This is my output.  What am I doing wrong?  Also if anyone has compiled dll's for mesa using up to date mesa and mingw, or VS2012, then please share!

Here is my output, I haven't programmed python in a long time but it appears a map/dictionary doesn't contain the key/value pair.

```
C:\Downloads\MesaLib-9.1.5\Mesa-9.1.5>scons platform=windows toolchain=crossming
w machine=x86_64 mesagdi libgl-gdi

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
KeyError: 'CCVERSION':
  File "C:\Downloads\MesaLib-9.1.5\Mesa-9.1.5\SConstruct", line 40:
    ENV = os.environ,
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.0\SCons\Environment.py", line 1002:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.0\SCons\Environment.py", line 106:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.0\SCons\Environment.py", line 1786:
    tool(self)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.0\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Downloads\MesaLib-9.1.5\Mesa-9.1.5\scons\gallium.py", line 313:
    ccversion = env['CCVERSION']
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.0\SCons\Environment.py", line 412:
    return self._dict[key]
```

Comment: You're going to have to do better than that if you want an answer. Just saying "I went through a FAQ and it didn't work" isn't enough to answer anything. You didn't even bother to link to the FAQ in question, let alone tell us exactly what you did.

Comment: Never could get MinGW to build workable Mesa binaries.  Haven't tried recently though.  What are you trying to cross-compile to?  Win64 from Win32?

Comment: Not trying to cross compile, just want to build openGL on this platform.  The reason toolchain=crossmingw is because thats what the instructions said to do.  I followed the instructions on the compiling/installing page of mesa's site.  I followed each step, and every step was a success, except the last step which is a scons command to compile, I'm not sure what you expect me to tell you about that, the steps are listed on the page.  What I ment by the FAQ was the FAQ page on mesa's site.  There wasn't much on the FAQ that was relevant, I just wanted to point out that I did in fact read it.

Comment: @genpfault did you get it compiled with Visual studio?

Comment: @EddieV223: I did.  See answer.

Answer (score 17):

Common `scons` options:

```
build=release
machine=x86
platform=windows
libgl-gdi
```

1. <s>Linux (Debian Wheezy), `toolchain=crossmingw`: **Fails** during linking phase because it can't find `__vscprintf`, among other things.</s> **Works** as of Debian Jessie 8.5 & Mesa `d2f42a945ec0fbcc51b59cfd329258bd62ebf0d2` via:

   ```
   scons \
   toolchain=crossmingw \
   build=release \
   machine=x86 \
   platform=windows \
   libgl-gdi
   ```

   DLL is installed to `build/windows-x86/gallium/targets/libgl-gdi/opengl32.dll`
2. Windows, `toolchain=mingw`: **Fails** with "The command line is too long." despite multiple permutations of both snippits on [`LongCmdLinesOnWin32`](http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32).
3. Windows, VS2012 Express, `MSVC_VERSION=11.0`: **Succeeds** after removing [stray C99-isms](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/commit/src/glsl/ralloc.c?id=392f6cfced304e8693fc93279560ab5dcc033d02) from `src/glsl/ralloc.c::ralloc_size()`.

---

**EDIT**: More complete procedure:

1. Install Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop:

   ```
   http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop
   ```
2. Install MinGW:

   ```
   http://www.mingw.org/
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files
   mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe

   Run installer:
   Download latest repo catalogs
   Install to C:\MinGW (default)
   Check:
   * C compiler
   * C++ compiler
   * MSYS basic system
   * MinGW developer toolkit (should install msys-flex and msys-bison)
   ```
3. Install Python 2.7:

   ```
   http://www.python.org/download/
   http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/python-2.7.5.msi

   You have to use 32-bit Python because the Scons people only distribute 32-bit installers.

   Install for all users (default)
   Install to C:\Python27 (default)
   Use default install options/customizations
   ```
4. Install `libxml2` for Python:

   ```
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
   libxml2-python-2.9.1.win32-py2.7.‌exe

   Installer should find the python install automagically
   ```
5. Install `pywin32`:

   ```
   http://pywin32.sourceforge.net/
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe

   Installer should find the Python install automagically
   ```
6. Install `Scons`:

   ```
   http://www.scons.org/
   http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/scons/scons-2.3.0-setup.exe

   Installer should find the Python install automagically
   ```
7. Add these near the top of your `PATH`:

   ```
   C:\Python27\
   C:\Python27\Scripts
   ```
8. Download Mesa:

   ```
   ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/
   ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/9.1.5/MesaLib-9.1.5.zip

   Extract somewhere (C:\Mesa-9.1.5)
   ```
9. Start MSYS shell:

   ```
   C:\mingw\msys\1.0\msys.bat

   Change into mesa src directory:
   cd /c/Mesa-9.1.5/
   ```
10. Build Mesa:

    ```
    scons.py \
    build=release \
    machine=x86 \
    platform=windows \
    MSVC_VERSION=11.0 \
    libgl-gdi \
    ```

This should create an `opengl32.dll` in `build\windows-x86\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi`.

With a [little bit more legwork](https://sites.google.com/site/buildllvmpipe/) it's possible to build `llvmpipe`.

Comment: Applying the `ralloc.c` fix and your 10 steps (exactly), I was able to successfully compile `Mesa-9.1.5`. Thanks. :D

Comment: Since 64 bit Windows 7 is very common today (in year 2014), if you want to build a 64-bit opengl32.dll on 64bit Windows 7, specify machine=x86_64. PS: it is 64bit age now, it is surprising that we still have to work with command line often. It's something like leading a primitive life in modern society. I'm not clear if it is a good thing.