# How to specify including path in MinGW?

Tags: c++, path, mingw

I tried to follow steps in the answer to this post:"[Building Mesa for windows 7. Mesa 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871781/building-mesa-for-windows-7-mesa-9-1)". But when I run scons.py, I got the following error:

```
$ scons.py build=release machine=x86 platform=windows MSVC_VERSION=12.0 libgl-gdi

scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: VC version 12.0 not installed.  C/C++ compilers are most likely not set correctly.
 Installed versions are: ['11.0']

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Mesa-10.4.4\scons\gallium.py", line 140,
in generate
Checking for MSVC ...  yes
Checking for X11 (x11 xext xdamage xfixes glproto >= 1.4.13)... no
Checking for XCB (x11-xcb xcb-glx >= 1.8.1 xcb-dri2 >= 1.8)... no
Checking for XF86VIDMODE (xxf86vm)... no
Checking for DRM (libdrm >= 2.4.38)... no
Checking for UDEV (libudev >= 151)... no
warning: LLVM disabled: not building llvmpipe
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
  Compiling src\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.c ...
libgl_gdi.c
src\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.c(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [build\windows-x86\gallium\targets\libgl-gdi\libgl_gdi.obj] Error 2
  Compiling src\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_context.c ...
stw_context.c
src\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_context.c(28) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
scons: *** [build\windows-x86\gallium\state_trackers\wgl\stw_context.obj] Error
2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I'm having Visual Studio 2013 installed so I changed the version of MSVC_VERSION from 11.0 to 12.0. I have tried adding a new environmental variable C_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC but it does not work. no idea of how to work on MinGW. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "VS2012 Tools Command Prompt", `chdir <src_dir>`, and run scons.

**Update:**

Run from Start menu >> Programs >> Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 >> Visual Studio Tools >> Command Promt.

The `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` will be run. It will setup `INCLUDE`, `LIB`, `LIBPATH` and some other variables.

Run `scons` in this console window.