# Compiling Mesa3D windows 64bit

Tags: windows, scons, mesa

I am new to opengl and mesa3D library I have some problem in compiling mesa3d library on windows 8.1 64 bit machine..
I tried to follow this post [Building Mesa for windows 7. Mesa 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871781/building-mesa-for-windows-7-mesa-9-1) but I didn't succeed when I try to build the library with scons by this command

```
scons platform=windows toolchain=mingw machine=x86_64 mesagdi libgl-gdi
```

I get the following error

```
Checking for X11 (x11 xext xdamage xfixes)... no
Checking for XCB (x11-xcb xcb-glx >= 1.8.1)... no
Checking for XF86VIDMODE (xxf86vm)... no
Checking for DRM (libdrm >= 2.4.24)... no
Checking for DRM_INTEL (libdrm_intel >= 2.4.30)... no
Checking for XORG (xorg-server >= 1.6.0)... no
Checking for KMS (libkms >= 2.4.24)... no
Checking for UDEV (libudev > 150)... no
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Compressed\Mesa\SConstruct", line 151:
    duplicate = 0 # http://www.scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x2261.html
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 614:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 551:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Compressed\Mesa\src\SConscript", line 27:
    SConscript('mesa/SConscript')
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 614:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 551:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Compressed\Mesa\src\mesa\SConscript", line 453:
    write_git_sha1_h_file("main/git_sha1.h")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Compressed\Mesa\src\mesa\SConscript", line 448:
    os.rename(tempfile, filename)
```

Even though there is a SConstruct file in the given path

Comment: I dont think its a problem that SCons cant find the SConstruct script, but rather the path specified on line 151 of the SConstruct file is missing.
Also, even though it has nothing to do with SCons, you should look into the git error too.

Comment: What is that git error,Which is not a git repo how do I know it

Comment: Something is trying to do a git command, and its not in a local git repo.

Comment: I dont know, that has nothing to do with SCons. You should contact the Mesa project folks, they will have much more context about how it should work. Personally, I think the build system is expecting certain things from git to be in place, but they're missing.