# Software-only openGL32.dll?

Tags: opengl, dll

I have multiple machines that do not have openGL capable graphics controllers (or at least not for the OS I am using), and I am trying to run various softwares which require openGL32.dll to be present and working.  I only need openGL version 1.4 compatibility.

My question:  Is there some sort of software-only emulation for openGL that I can use to run these?  I have heard of MESA, but all I need is the dll, and MESA seems to require that I build everything manually.

I am running Windows 10 x86_64

Comment: You must use Mesa.  The opengl32.dll on Windows only provides OpenGL 1.1.  Mesa is also faster.

Comment: It [isn't too hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871781/building-mesa-for-windows-7-mesa-9-1).

Comment: I'll give it a shot...  Although I have basically no idea what I'm doing.  I've never built anything for Windows before (although I've done plenty on Linux and OS X)

Comment: If the machines have Direct3D 9 you can use ANGLE. https://github.com/google/angle

Comment: Hmm, not sure about Direct3D, but I think I've got DirectX 9.  How do I check for Direct3D 9?

Comment: And that's openGL ES.  This software doesn't work with ES I don't think.

Comment: If it helps, I'm trying to run Quake3

Comment: `scons: building terminated because of errors` and a ton of output.  Too long to post here.  No sign of openGL32.dll anywhere in the MESA directory.  Anybody got a prebuilt version of MESA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty surprised that a machine running Windows 10 does not have a GPU capable of supporting OpenGL-1.4 – most likely you simply don't have the proper drivers installed and that's all your troubles. OpenGL dates back almost 15 years; that was before shaders where are thing.

The default Windows installation does not ship with fully featured OpenGL drivers, because Microsoft in all their wisdom decided, that they'd strip perfectly working OpenGL drivers from the drivers installed through Windows automatic driver installation.

To get full and proper OpenGL support you absolutely *must* download the drivers *directly* from your GPU vendors website and install those. Open up the "Hardware Manager", look for "Graphics adapter", there you find the name of it. Type the name plus "driver Windows" into the little box of Google and it will carry you to the right place.

Comment: Well, here's the thing: I don't buy computers, I am given dozens of parts and I create a Frankenstein computer.  This machine is a rare case:  It's a 2011 Macbook Pro that's missing the GPU.  The Intel chip has Intel HD Graphics 3000, and I can't find any drivers that work with Windows 10, nor can I find the chip in Device Manager.  I have manually disabled the discreet GPU in Device Manager, and it's the only display adaptor showing up.  I can give you screenshots if you like...  Just ask for a screen and I'll try to get it to you.

Comment: @Daniel: This should match the Intel GPU: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25176/Intel-HD-Graphics-Production-Driver-for-Windows-10-64-bit-N-Series-

Comment: @Daniel: Also when it comes to identifying the hardware using a Live Linux distribution (like GRML) works wonders. If you could boot GRML and paste the output of `lspci` somewhere I could give you exact links to the drivers to download.

Comment: I can try that, but it's a Macbook Pro, and the GPU is severely messed up.  It will need to be 100% text based, and bootable on a MBP.  Can you give me a link to the Linux image?

Comment: I'll try those Intel drivers, but it's an i7 CPU.

Comment: @Daniel: GRML is 100% text based; once it's booted you can opt to start an X server, but you can just as well drop into a text mode shell. http://grml.org/ – the ISO image works on a USB storage device as well, just copy it with dd.

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I can.  I'm doing homework at the moment, but I'll link to a pastebin when I can.

Comment: I wonder, can I use an SD card to boot? - Apparently MBPs can boot off the SD card \*evil laugh\*

Comment: GRML stops on `Loading the GRML file...This could take a few seconds.`  and does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102782/discussion-between-daniel-and-datenwolf).

Answer (score 0):

Mesa3D seems to publish its own versions of it: https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag